# Wordpress Ajax always returns 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I am trying to make a form that validates if an url exists dynamically and am having problems with Wordpress ajax call ALWAYS returning 0. I have also been researching for about 3 hours now about this and nothing seems to work for me, it might be a dumb question. Here is what I have done so far:

I have a button:

```
<input id="analyze"type="button" class="analyze-button" value="Analyze">
```

And I am trying to run this script on it (located in another file):

```
$(document).on('click', '#analyze', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: checkurl.ajax_url,    
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'checkUrl',
            //link_check : $('#main-input').val(),
        }, success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }, error:function(msg){
            alert("Error");
        }        
    });
});
```

This is how I added the ajax hooks:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checkUrl', 'checkUrl' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_checkUrl', 'checkUrl' );

function checkUrl(){
    echo "I works1";
    if(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX){
        echo "I work";
    }

    echo "I works";
    die();
}
```

And this is how I enqueued the script:

```
function ajax_contact(){
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxcontact', get_template_directory_uri() .'/templates/ajaxcontact.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('ajaxcontact', 'checkurl', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_contact');
```

Last 2 code snippets were from **function.php**

What am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of things, but with no luck so far.

[This](http://alegrapractic.ro/contact-form/) is the link to the page where I have the form. It is a test page right now. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, maybe try renaming `checkUrl` to `check_url`.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić first time it was 'check_url' and then I renamed it a few times thinking that maybe that was causing it.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić I have edited the post to include the link to the form, maybe I was missing something.

Comment: Well, currently it returns `I works1` so it looks like it works. :)

Comment: @IgorJerosimić I think it was because of the browser. I fired up another one and it worked. Maybe it was because of the cookies. Do you have any Idea how to get it working in chrome? I cleared cookies and refreshed the page a few times.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't forget to stop execution afterward.

`wp_die();`