# Simple WordPress AJAX resulting in 400 Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I've pored over other threads' WordPress AJAX questions with 400 errors, but I just can't seem to get this right.

I am in WordPress trying to implement some AJAX. Right now I have dummy functions in place just to learn about the AJAX functionality, but I can't get them to work.

On my page template, I have this Javascript at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var data = { action : 'bp_check_user_role' };
jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function (success) { console.log(success); });
</script>
```

In my Code Snippets plugin, I have this PHP:

```
function bp_check_user_role() {
    echo "Hi!";
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_bp_check_user_role', 'bp_check_user_role');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bp_check_user_role', 'bp_check_user_role');
```

I feel like I'm doing these two steps properly, but when I load the page the code doesn't work and I get this (I've scrubbed {mysite}, but it is correct):

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST https://{mysite}.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 ()
```

Any ideas or obvious mistakes I am making? I just can't seem to crack this one :(

Threads I've read in addition to referring to the WordPress Codex:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220661/use-ajax-without-a-plugin
[Wordpress Ajax always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844565/wordpress-ajax-always-returns-0)

Comment: Visit `https://{mysite}.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bp_check_user_role` and see if you see the "Hi!" text. If not, then your AJAX action is likely registered *after* WordPress fires all registered AJAX actions.

Comment: It returned 0 - thanks for the lead. The Code Snippets plugin I use for the PHP has an option to run code only on the front-end or back-end only, and in an attempt to be efficient I was only running the PHP Front-end. I switched this to Back-end only and now it works!

Comment: Sally if you post an answer I'll happily comment how the debugging step helped me and mark it as correct :) Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion/comment helped you. I've posted an answer and hopefully it will also help others. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've pointed in my comment:

> Visit
>   `https://{mysite}.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bp_check_user_role`
>   and see if you see the "*Hi!*" text.

**Why visit that URL?**

To verify that your AJAX 'action' is registered (properly) and that the AJAX response is also as you expected.

### Additional Note

If you look at the code in `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, you'd see these:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    ...
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    // If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
    if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
        wp_die( '0', 400 );
    }

    ...
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
```

So as you can see, it says `// If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.`, and therefore, if your AJAX JavaScript callback receives a *400 Bad Request* error/response, then your AJAX 'action' is likely *not* registered, or that the PHP callback for the 'action' did *not* get called because the 'action' was registered *after* the `do_action()` call.

That may not always be the case; however, it can be a very good "first-aid" in troubleshooting AJAX issues.

Comment: For others with this problem, I was running my PHP code in a snippet via the 'Code Snippets' plugin and had selected 'only run on the front end'. This prevented the code from executing in the wp-admin area, thus never registering my AJAX actions for wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to discover. Thanks again Sally for helping me!